# call third party web service using apache camel

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel

I am new to camel

I am trying to call webservice using camel java dsl

```
from("cxf://http://darshan:8080/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort?wsdlURL=http://darshan:8080/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort?wsdl&serviceName={http://ws.test.com/}SampleTestServiceService&portName={http://ws.test.com/}SampleTestServicePort&dataFormat=MESSAGE")
```

following is my wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.test.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://ws.test.com/" name="SampleTestServiceService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.test.com/" schemaLocation="http://darshan:808O/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort?xsd=1"></xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="sayHello">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHello"></part>
    </message>
    <message name="sayHelloResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:sayHelloResponse"></part>
    </message>
    <portType name="SampleTestServiceDelegate">
        <operation name="sayHello">
            <input message="tns:sayHello"></input>
            <output message="tns:sayHelloResponse"></output>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="SampleTestServicePortBinding" type="tns:SampleTestServiceDelegate">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"></soap:binding>
        <operation name="sayHello">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SampleTestServiceService">
        <port name="SampleTestServicePort" binding="tns:SampleTestServicePortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://darshan:808O/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort"></soap:address>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

That gives no error but also output is nothing.

Please suggest me what is wrong in my code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am wondering if the second `&` (here: `SampleTestServicePort?wsdl`) needs to be escaped?

Comment: And how should we supposed to tell, what is wrong with your code without your code here?

Comment: Thanks for giving response

Comment: there is no issue with & 
i used following post as a reference 
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585877/how-to-call-a-third-party-webservice-using-apache-camel-using-cxf-componnet).

Comment: Thanks herry for formatting my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the Apache CXF Component as a `from()` what you are doing is you are hosting the webservice instead of accessing a third-party one.

To access a third-party service you need to use the `to()` form of the component. You need to do something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:./myFileRequest?delay=1000&amp;include=myRequest.xml">
  <to uri="cxf://http://darshan:8080/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort?wsdlURL=http://darshan:8080/sampleWebService/SampleTestServicePort?wsdl&serviceName={http://ws.test.com/}SampleTestServiceService&portName={http://ws.test.com/}SampleTestServicePort&dataFormat=MESSAGE" />
  ...
</route>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: hveiga Thanks for response 
but there is no argument available in remote method.
and please let me know content of file myRequest.xml 
& what is  myFileRequest??

Comment: Well, it depends how the third-party service works. You either need to send a request with the expected format or use a SOAPAction. If you are using a request, that's what the file should be.

Answer (score 0):

Define the cxf bean as below in the camel context

```xml
<cxf:cxfEndpoint
    address="Service ENDPOINT"
    endpointName="give wsdl:port@name here from wsdl"
    id="any id" loggingFeatureEnabled="true"
    serviceClass="your service class - it will be inside the stubs generated from WSDL"
    serviceName="Service Name"
    wsdlURL="WSDL path" xmlns:ws="namespace">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

then write the following in your route:

```xml
<to id="_to1" uri="cxf:bean:id Of the cxfEndpoint bean"/>
```